# add server side data into html list?

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt

i am new in gwt.i want to add data come from serverside in html listbox,so how can w do this??
name is splitted string which i want to add in the listbox...
actually i want to make jqxlistbox type module.http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxlistbox/index.htm

```
public class imagegrid implements EntryPoint 
{
    Label l = new Label("search");
TextBox tb=new TextBox();
VerticalPanel panel=new VerticalPanel();

String name=null;

private final GreetingServiceAsync greetingService = GWT.create(GreetingService.class);

public void onModuleLoad()
{
    tb.addKeyUpHandler(new handler());
    panel.add(l);
    panel.add(tb);
    RootPanel.get().add(panel);
}

public class handler implements KeyUpHandler
{
    public void onKeyUp(KeyUpEvent event) 
    {
        String ab =tb.getText();

        if(ab.length()>0)
        {
            greetingService.server(ab,new AsyncCallback<String>()
            {

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Throwable caught) 
                {
                    Window.alert("Invalid");
                }

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(String result) 
                { 
                    System.out.println("At the client side..."+result);

                    if(result.isEmpty())
                    { 
                        name="not found";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        String match=tb.getText();

                        for (String retval: result.split("/"))
                        {
                            name=retval;
                        }
                    }
                }

            });
          }
      }
 }
}
```

Comment: Anything from a `RequestBuilder` to `RCP` to a `RequestFactory` would work - you need to be more specific as to your use case and exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: i want to make searching module just like in google+ searching friend..in which i required a list in which i use css and add images also..and i have made a module gwt listbox but its not working as i want

Comment: Try with [Advanced GWT Components](http://advanced-gwt.sourceforge.net/text-and-button.html) such as complex drop down.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is [CellList](http://gwt.googleusercontent.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCellList) in GWT. You can find the sample code in showcase.

Sorry, I missed the search part of your question. For that you may need to create a new implementation og SuggestBox with CellList as drop-down. Like someone has shown [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-web-toolkit/n9XClDXvtAk).